# Pluralisation of bibliography fields based on content

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, plural

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}      

\usepackage{biblatex,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@book{book1,
  author    = {A Author},
  title     = {A title},
  chapter   = {1},
  publisher = {A publisher},
  year      = {2000}
}
@book{book2,
  author    = {B Author},
  title     = {B Title},
  chapter   = {1-3},
  publisher = {B publisher},
  year      = {2001}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{chapter}{Chapter~\mkcomprange{#1}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How do I update the declared format for the `chapter` field (specific to an `@book` entry in this case) so that I'm able to distinguish between single and multiple chapter entries. That is, `book1` should print as-is, while `book2` should print `Chapters 1-5` (note the pluralisation).

[image]

I tried

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{chapter}{%
  Chapter\ifnumcomp{\rangelen{chapter}}{>}{1}{s}{}~\mkcomprange{#1}}
```

but `\rangelen` expects a field that has been defined as containing a range, and `chapter` is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the checks `\ifnumeral` and `\ifnumerals`. The former checks for a number and the second for a range of numbers. We can probably safely assume that `\ifnumeral` will yield 'true' where you want a singular string and `\ifnumerals` for a plural string.

I suggest that additionally you also use bibliography strings. `chapter` already exists, but there is no plural form `chapters`

```
\NewBibliographyString{chapters}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  chapter  = {chapter},
  chapters = {chapters}
}
```

Then you could use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{chapter}{%
  \ifnumerals{#1}
    {\ifnumeral{#1}
       {\bibstring{chapter}}
       {\bibstring{chapters}}}
    {}%
  ~\mkcomprange{#1}}
```

or

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{chapter}{%
  \ifnumeral{#1}
    {\bibstring{chapter}}
    {\ifnumerals{#1}
       {\bibstring{chapters}}
       {}}%
  ~\mkcomprange{#1}}
```

The latter is  more or less what `\mkpageprefix` does.